# Add a row to a data frame, which is the sum of 2 existing rows

Tags: python, pandas, sum, row

I'm having trouble finding the right code to add a row to my data frame that is the sum of 2 existing rows in the data frame.

So far I have this as my code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(20, 5)), columns=['First','Second','Third','Fourth','Fifth'],index=list('abcdefghijklmnopqrst'))

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'First':['0'],'Second':['1'],'Third':['-1'],'Fourth':['2'],'Fifth':['-2']},index=["u"])

df3 = pd.concat([df,df2],axis=0,join='inner')
print(df3)
```

I want to add a row "v" to df3, where row "v" is the sum of rows "b" and "d" of df3

Below are my attempts, but I can't seem to figure it out! Please let me know if I got anywhere close. Thanks in advance :)

```
df4 = df3["b","d"].sum()
df4= df3["b"].add(df3["d"], index=["v"])
df3.loc['v'] = df.sum("b", "d")
df3.loc['v',"First','Second','Third','Fourth','Fifth'] = df3.sum("b", "d")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem right now seems to be that to think way too complicated. It's really as simple as saying *row called 'v' is the sum of row called 'b' and row called 'd'. Or in pandas syntax:
`df.loc['v'] = df.loc['b'] + df.loc['d']`

If you really need to use the sum() function, you have to understand how it works on the data frame. In your case you'd first have to select the respective rows (which will return a view of these rows as pandas.DataFrame) and then use the sum() function of this view like this:
`df.loc['v'] = df.loc[['b','d']].sum()`

Works for me using pandas 0.23.3 and python 3.6.

Comment: Thanks so much, I'm just learning Pandas and your explanation helped alot!

Comment: I'm glad I could help. The main difference to numpy arrays, at least here, is that the indexing in pandas is different. It's definitely a good idea to go through the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Using `append`

```
df3.append(df3.loc[["b","d"],:].sum().to_frame('v').T)
Out[520]: 
  First Second Third Fourth Fifth
a    27     77    54     39    23
b    84     37    99     87    37
c    63     25    11     71    44
d    70      4    71     63    86
e    50     78    70      6    78
f    53     50    31     72    87
g    10      5    28     79    56
h    68     15    13     71    38
i    17     12    12     15    46
j    37     90    24      2    36
k    47     91    55     54     9
l     4     10    12     18    27
m    68     86    83     83    11
n    41     46    93     15     8
o    80     29    68     94    16
p    36     81    43     61    44
q     5     10    92     47    40
r    70      0    58     55    36
s    22     76    99     21    61
t    24     75     5     81    47
u     0      1    -1      2    -2
v   154     41   170    150   123
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df3.loc['v']=df3.loc['b'] + df3.loc['d']
```